# How to restart Background service getting killed on redmi phone For MIUM 8

Tags: android, service, background, background-service, android-background

I am using `sticky service` for background operations and its working fine in all phones even when app is `closed` by swiping from stack(then service is restart) but in `RedMi Note 3w` When app is closed by swiping from stack , `service is not restarting` .I test Whats App and its working fine on Note 3 so it means `WhatsApp` is able to manage this so how can we restart Background service getting killed on redmi phone?

**Note :** please don't give me solution for MIUM 7

Comment: you should height light the programming key like `this` or use bold.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , i will take care of it @SohailZahid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in **MIUI 8** in **setting >Permissions>Autostart** you can **allow your app to Auto Start** and Facebook and WhatsApp are already allowed because MIUI 8 by default allowed auto Start for whatsApp and Facebook as they are very popular App brands