# Service stop's whenever app is killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

START_STICKY don't work in my device whenever i kill my app then service don't start again, My device name is Redmi Note 3 Pro, but whenever i run same app in android emulator, it restarts the service when i kill the app and service don't stops until i stop it by stopService() method

please help me out

**Problem Solved**

> Done this:

**setting >Permissions>Autostart**
then **turned on the Switch of my app**, and Done!

**I got solution in this link: [Solution Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39269523/8362967)**

Comment: Use `ServiceConnection` and service binding for to keep service without destroying

Comment: @HemanthSTobi ok will try it, thanks for helping though appreciate it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add "android:process=:any_name" in the manifest under the inside the service attributes.

For example,

```
      <service android:name=".MyService"
        android:process=":MyService"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

Below is the code of my Service class.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");
    Toast.makeText(AppController.getInstance(),"Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("servicedestroy", "servicedestroy");
    Toast.makeText(AppController.getInstance(),"service destroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {

                                  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          Toast.makeText(AppController.getInstance(),"Running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                      }
                                  });


                              }

                          },
            0,
            5000);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

}

Comment: yup i know this works by using AlarmManager in onTaskRemoved or in onDestroy, just forgot to share it here, well thanks for answer

Comment: it didnt work for me, is the process name just a random name?!

Comment: @Keivan.k  yes it can be any name as per your choice ..

Comment: I check this on Redmi phone when I remove the app the foreground service is kill and its start foreground service after 5seconds but when i again open the application and clear again from recent then second time its not start foreground service. Any Solution?

Comment: @AnwarZahid  have you mentioned the Service class in your manifest properly ?

Comment: @VivekKumar yes . <service android:name=".services.FlashService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":anyname"
            android:foregroundServiceType="camera"/>
    </application>

Comment: But I think its issue of battery optimization.

Comment: Here is my service in manifest   <service
            android:name=".services.FlashService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="camera"
            android:process=":anyname"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />

Comment: while service same as you posted answer above

Answer (score 6):

On some devices (notably Xiaomi, Huawei, Lenovo) you need to add your app to a list of "protected apps" or "apps that are allowed to run in the background". If your app isn't in the list, Android will NOT automatically restart your `Service`, even if you have returned `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`. This is a "battery saving feature" that unfortunately makes a lot of problems for developers!

Look in the Android settings under Power management, Security or Apps for these settings.

See also:

- [clear Recent apps wipe the apps memory and my receiver stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277671/clear-recent-apps-wipe-the-apps-memory-and-my-receiver-stopped-working/41369032#41369032)
- [Android Service is terminated when App destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703717/android-service-is-terminated-when-app-destroyed/41703954#41703954)
- [Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 custom service not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419571/xiaomi-redmi-note-3-custom-service-not-working/45419613#45419613)
- [onTaskRemoved() not getting called in HUAWEI and XIOMI devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660216/ontaskremoved-not-getting-called-in-huawei-and-xiomi-devices/42120277#42120277)

Please also explain what you mean by "kill my app". If you force close your app, then the `Service` will NOT be restarted by Android. This is intentional, and it also won't be restarted on the emulator if you force close the app.

Comment: Thanks man it worked i have enabled auto start by **setting >Permissions>Autostart** n ya i got solution in this link: [Solution Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39269523/8362967)

Comment: What about the foreground service?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I don't understand your question. Normally Android won't kill a foreground `Service`, but in this case, I assume that if Android kills your foreground `Service` (for whatever reason), it still won't restart it unless your app is added to this list of apps.

Comment: @DavidWasser thanks, you answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

Code might help you in `HourlyService` class `onStartCommand` method returns `START_STICKY`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Inside Activity

```
 private HourlyService mHourlyService;
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) iBinder;
        mHourlyService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HourlyService.class);
    bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    mBound = false;
}
```